# Ionic2 + Angular2 or React-native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, ionic2

Which one is better for CRUD app, Ionic2 (already in beta now) or React-native?
Performance is not my priority, but the application should be responsible smooth enough with touch/swipe event.

Comment: I'd like to know if it's possible to use ionic2 with React-native at the same time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Though I have used *Ionic framework* earlier and currently working with *React-native*. I think I would suggest you to go for *React-native*. They haven't released beta version yet. But you can surely work out that through some hack and jacks.

**Ionic Framework** basically uses PhoneGap/Cordova which makes your application run in a webview of your Phone. That is where you can use HTML Javascript to build anything and everything with the help of great community available to support you online and great list of Plugins (and very easy to use them) with ng-cordova. It makes your job easy to develop apps. But then Performance. It lags. It lags way to much. Once your application is done all you would be upto is to make your app faster. It gives best results in Iphone but not in Android.

Where **React-native** has compressed the gap between Native and Cross platform app development. You use all the Native Elements for the view. You won't find any webview in it. You code in Javascript with subtle syntax. Perfomance, Oh man Oh, amazing. But yes, for React-native you need little knowledge about Native UI elements of IOS and Android both.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know is react-native support full touch event ?

Comment: Yes It support full touch event. Gesture responder System and PanResponder are add on to it. You can drag frames with touch in react-native. But thats not possible for now in Ionic framework other than slidebox.

Comment: Thanks for useful info, I'll try to use it.

Answer (score 3):

You can watch and test applications created with ionic [here](http://showcase.ionicframework.com) to see the real performance.

And the performance in **ionic2/angular2** is better now (compared with v1, beside that v2 is still in early beta stage). I don't agree with that it lags, is just depends of:

- How big is your app.
- How well coded it is.
- How much graphic elements and/or animations you will need.

And with Crosswalk you can have a really good performance with it.

Ionic is growing really fast, yesterday they [released the platform beta](http://blog.ionic.io/announcing-the-ionic-platform-beta/) which have a lot of nice services. And maybe you want to check de [ionic discover](http://ionic.io/discover).

About **react-native** i never tried so ofcourse i am not saying ionic is a better option. It just depends of what you need, what you know and how you will do it. As far as i see react-native can get better performance but with more difficult learning curve.